# Debug Assertion Failed: map/set iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project, and as part of it I need to create a map with the first value as a string, and the second is a pointer to a class.

So I declared it map`<string, Objectfactory*> Objlib`

The `Objectfactory` class has a function called `create()` which returns a pointer to a class called `Object`.

So I have the following code:

```
Object* newobject = (*Objlib.find("string")).second->create();
```

The program compiles just fine, but I get a run time error at that line of code saying that
the map/set iterator is not dereferencable.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What happens if an entry with key `"string"` isn't in the map? You get an iterator to the `end()` element. You can't de-reference that.

So, check if your map contains the element before de-referencing:

```
auto it = Objlib.find("string");
Object* newObject = it == Objlib.end() ? nullptr : it->second->create();
```

This calls the `create()` method only if the element exists in the map. Otherwise, newObject is set to `nullptr`.